# Difference between gob decoding an interface in a struct, vs. raw

Tags: go, gob

I have been struggling to understand the difference between encoding/decoding an interface type when that type is embedded in a struct, vs. when it's not embedded at all.

Using the following example: [here in the playground](http://play.golang.org/p/pM8XgonIwH)

Note the code declares an interface `IFace`. It declares a non-exported struct `impl`. It sets up a few Gob methods to `Register`, `GobEncode`, and `GobDecode` the `impl` struct.

Then, it also declares a struct `Data` which is exported, and has a single field `Foo` which is of the interface type `IFace`.

So, there's an interface, a struct which implements it, and a container struct which has a field whose value is that interface type.

My problem is that the container struct `Data` is happily sent through the Gob gauntlet, and, when it goes through, it happily encodes and decodes the IFace field in the `Data` struct... great! But, I cannot seem to be able to send just an instance of the IFace value through the gob gauntlet.

What is the magic invocation I am missing?

Searching for the error message gives a number of results, but I believe I have satisfied the Gob contract.... and the "proof" of that is in the successful struct gobbing. Obviously I have missed something, but can't see it.

Note, the output of the program is:

```
Encoding {IFace:bilbo} now
Encoding IFace:baggins now
Decoded {IFace:bilbo} now
decode error: gob: local interface type *main.IFace can only be decoded from remote interface type; received concrete type impl
Decoded <nil> now
```

The actual code is:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/gob"
    "fmt"
)

type IFace interface {
    FooBar() string
}

type impl struct {
    value string
}

func init() {
    gob.Register(impl{})
}

func (i impl) FooBar() string {
    return i.value
}

func (i impl) String() string {
    return "IFace:" + i.value
}

func (i impl) GobEncode() ([]byte, error) {
    return []byte(i.value), nil
}

func (i *impl) GobDecode(dat []byte) error {
    val := string(dat)
    i.value = val
    return nil
}

func newIFace(val string) IFace {
    return impl{val}
}

type Data struct {
    Foo IFace
}

func main() {

    var network bytes.Buffer        // Stand-in for a network connection
    enc := gob.NewEncoder(&network) // Will write to network.
    dec := gob.NewDecoder(&network) // Will read from network.

    var err error

    var bilbo IFace
    bilbo = newIFace("bilbo")

    var baggins IFace
    baggins = newIFace("baggins")

    dat := Data{bilbo}

    fmt.Printf("Encoding %v now\n", dat)
    err = enc.Encode(dat)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("encode error:", err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Encoding %v now\n", baggins)
    err = enc.Encode(baggins)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("encode error:", err)
    }

    var pdat Data
    err = dec.Decode(&pdat)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("decode error:", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Decoded %v now\n", pdat)

    var pbag IFace
    err = dec.Decode(&pbag)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("decode error:", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Decoded %v now\n", pbag)

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32428797/go-rpc-call-is-fine-locally-marshalling-issue-when-using-rpc/32430429#32430429

Comment: @JiangYD - that Unmarshal method is for `encoding/json`. Is there an equivalent for `encoding/gob`?

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/#GobDecoder

Comment: OK, @JiangYD - the code I have in the question is using GobDecoder and GobEncoder (and it's working when the interface is embedded in a struct, but not when the interface is stand-alone).

Comment: that's not broke the `the reflector knows the underlying type` problem. change interface to struct, and embed the dynamic types in that struct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The call

```
err = enc.Encode(baggins)
```

passes an `impl` value to `Encode`.  It does not pass a value of type `IFace`.   The document http://research.swtch.com/interfaces may be helpful in understanding why this is. The value is encoded as the concrete type `impl`.

If you want to decode to an interface type, then you must encode an interface type. One way to do this is to pass a pointer to the interface value:

```
err = enc.Encode(&baggins)
```

In this call, a `*IFace` is passed to Encode. After dereferencing the pointer, the encoder sees that the value is an interface type and encodes it as an interface type. Because the gob package does all necessary dereferencing and indirection when converting values, the extra level of indirection on the call to Encode does not require an extra level of indirection when decoding.

<kbd>[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/YOCauG6Enh)</kbd>

Comment: So, when encoding a "raw" interface 'instance', a simple `&` in front of the variable is the magic, I really appreciate the link to that interfaces document too, Still reading it. I am going to declare the requirement to double-dereference the interface when encoding as "finicky" especially when the symptom of the problem is seen at decode time, not encode time. I guess if I look at the actual encoded stream I should see the difference though.